# two nested functions in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure if this is actually possible but I would have thought it is. I am very new to jquery. What I am trying to do is nest two functions.

Hide the target div
load the new page into the div
open up the div again

This works if I place the initial slideToggle on its own but I want to make sure the page is loaded before opening again

```
function nickyLoad(siteToFetch,whereToPut){
$('#'+whereToPut+'').slideToggle('slow', function() {// collapse target
    $('#'+whereToPut+'').load(siteToFetch, function() { //load new site
        $('#'+whereToPut+'').slideToggle('slow','');
    });
)};
```

}

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything seriously wrong with that; what is the problem?

Comment: Does it make your computer explode?  Does it give you head lice? Does it turn the screen all black suddenly?

Comment: @Pointy I hate it when I get lice :(

Comment: Its javascript... thus it results in none of the scripts working... 

Could it be that I cant use slideToggle within slideToggle?

Comment: @Pointy: Javascript fails silently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed up the order of `}` and `)` when closing the first slideToggle call (you've written `)};` instead of `});`

```
function nickyLoad(siteToFetch,whereToPut){
    $('#'+whereToPut+'').slideToggle('slow', function() {// collapse target
            $('#'+whereToPut+'').load(siteToFetch, function() { //load new site
                    $('#'+whereToPut+'').slideToggle('slow','');
            });
    }); //<-- corrected
}
```

These things (syntax errors) are easy to find with some simple tools. In firefox you can open the error console (Tools --> Error Console) and go to the "Error" tab. In Internet Explorer use the Developer Tools (Tools --> Developer Tools) and go to the "Script" tab.

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for firefox is also highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks. Ended up using a different script now :) will have a look at firebug!